# can i read the contents of file_store cache file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

We have a production app that is slowing down, one of the suspects is the file cache. Periodically, we are seeing gigantic file_store cache files, ex:

```
11044573 ./21D/AE1/menu_structure_5cb9b70e11e9b84ac9fa8412_super_admin
```

that leftmost number is the block size.  If we clear cache and the app regenerates the same file, it's way smaller:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 deploy deploy 19K Oct 23 17:27 ./21D/AE1/menu_structure_5cb9b70e11e9b84ac9fa8412_super_admin
```

(they're different formats b/c they were found with different commands but the first one is giant, the second one is 18K).  Everything works fine, so we think there must be some weird thing where a ton of extra data is defectively being stored in a cache file.  Is there a way see what's in there so we can debug why this is happening?

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dug through the rails source and here's the answer

```
cache_file_path = "tmp/cache/your_cache_file"
cache_entry = Marshal.load(File.read cache_file_path)
cache_entry.value
```

Comment: it raises the following error when doing so: `incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) format version 4.8 required; 0.17 given`

Answer (score 0):

To read cache entries run the following code:

```rb
cache_entry_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'cache', '20B', 'EB0', 'Users') # replace it with your cache entry path
Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, cache_entry_path).value # it returns the deserialized entry value
```

I tested it on Rails 6 and Rails 7, however is not granted it will work in future versions since it calls a private method.